# ExtJS 4 - Load grid from hyperlink

Tags: php, javascript, extjs4.1

I have a grid for which data is loaded dynamically from a server.

The subset of data to be loaded is based on various user selections made through other components on the page.  Once selections are made, a button is clicked, extraParams are set, and the grid data is loaded via PHP POST.  This is all working fine.

Question: What approach could I take to save the resulting page/grid view as a URL link? Or conversely, how can I load that page again (showing the data subset) via a URL?

(BTW I'm fine switching to PHP GET if it ends up being part of the solution.)

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be saving last selection to session variable so it's not depending on POST sending. So:

1. Send POST with filter
2. Save it to session
3. Redirect to same page to be sure that post data will be deleted on client side and not sent again
4. Reload the page will refresh the data

It can be used also for paginating - your filter will be always saved and you will send only request or new page (can be done only via GET or whatever you want to).

Next option is to save whole filter somewhere to database and create an unique hash for it. Than, just request the page again using this hash as GET parameter.